# Adding a <form> destroys layout

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, material-design

Im building a system using Angular6, Material and Flexbox.
I started building the layout of a form, and my result is the image below
[image]

Adding a simple `<form>` tag totally destroys the layout:

[image]

**Question:** Why does a form destroy the layout, and how can I fix this problem?

Code (its a bit long, perhaps just ctrl+f to find  tag and analyse why the tag destroys layout)

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px" style="min-height: 500px;">

    <mat-card fxFlex="50" fxLayout="row">
      <form> <!-- THIS FORMS DESTROYS LAYOUT -->
        <div fxFlex="45" fxLayout="column">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Navn på læge"/>
                <mat-error>Errors appear instantly!</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-select placeholder="Distrikt">
                <mat-option  [value]="1">
                  Distrikt 1
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option  [value]="2">
                  Distrikt 2
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option  [value]="2">
                  Distrikt 3
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option  [value]="2">
                  Distrikt 4
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option  [value]="2">
                  Distrikt 5
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option  [value]="2">
                  Distrikt 6
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-select placeholder="Projekt Sygeplejerske">
                <mat-option  [value]="1">
                  SP 1
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option  [value]="2">
                  SP 2
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option  [value]="2">
                  SP 3
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option  [value]="2">
                  SP 4
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-select placeholder="Account Manager">
                <mat-option  [value]="1">
                  AM 1
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option  [value]="2">
                  AM 2
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

            <div fxLayout="row">
                <mat-form-field fxFlex="45">
                  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Møde 1 Dato" disabled>
                  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #picker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
                <div fxFlex></div>
                <mat-form-field fxFlex="45">
                    <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Møde 1 klokkeslet"/>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <div fxLayout="row">
                <mat-form-field fxFlex="45">
                  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="Møde 2 Dato" disabled>
                  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #picker2 disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
                <div fxFlex></div>
                <mat-form-field fxFlex="45">
                    <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Møde 2 klokkeslet"/>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-select placeholder="EPJ System">
                <mat-option  [value]="1">
                  XMO
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option  [value]="2">
                  Clinea
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option  [value]="2">
                  NOVAX
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option  [value]="2">
                  WinPLC
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option  [value]="2">
                  Ganglion
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option  [value]="2">
                  Medwin
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

        </div>
        <div fxFlex></div>
        <div fxFlex="45" fxLayout="column">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input type="text" id="autocompleteInput" matInput autocofus placeholder="Søg adresse"/>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field>
                <input type="text" matInput disabled placeholder="Land"/>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field>
                <input type="text" matInput disabled placeholder="Vej"/>
            </mat-form-field>

            <div fxLayout="row">
                <mat-form-field fxFlex="45">
                    <input type="text" matInput disabled placeholder="Husnummer"/>
                </mat-form-field>
                <div fxFlex></div>
                <mat-form-field fxFlex="45">
                    <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Etage"/>
                </mat-form-field>    
            </div>
            <div fxLayout="row">
                <mat-form-field fxFlex="25">
                    <input type="text" matInput disabled placeholder="Postnummer"/>
                </mat-form-field>
                <div fxFlex></div>
                <mat-form-field fxFlex="65">
                    <input type="text" matInput disabled placeholder="By"/>
                </mat-form-field>    
            </div>
            <div fxFlex></div>
            <div fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                <button fxFlex="35" mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="/administrator/create_doctor">Opret læge</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </form> <!-- FORMS END TAG -->
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card fxFlex="50">
    <!-- LEFT OUT FOR SIMPLICITY --> 
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: It could be your selector that has no effect after `<form>` added. 
Normally it could be something like this `>` in selector
Better to have your CSS.

Comment: some css is applied to form, its better to have css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code makes the inputs form columns next to eachother: `<mat-card fxFlex="50" fxLayout="row">`
So when you add the `<form>` inside you have to give it the same css.

Try changin the `<form>` to `<form fxFlex="50" fxLayout="row">`.

Additionally you can remove the `fxFlex="50" fxLayout="row"` from `mat-card`

Comment: You are correct, adding `<form fxFlex="100" fxLayout="row">` solved the issue. It makes sense why the code behaves like this, thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and this is what i did. Might help someone in future.

Swap the lines where you place your form tag. In your case, move above the desired style.

```
<mat-card fxFlex="50" fxLayout="row">
   <form> <!-- THIS FORMS DESTROYS LAYOUT -->
```

Like this,

```
<form>
   <mat-card fxFlex="50" fxLayout="row">
```

Also, ensure you place your closing tag correctly according to this change.